# Does Sampling frequency come into picture in Samples generation for DAC to generate sinewave (analog signal with particular frequency & amplitude)?

Tags: sampling, digital-to-analog

I'm generating samples for dac  in STM32.
sin(2*pi*i /N)*4096/2.
This is the formula I'm using.
How to I come to know sampling frequency?
Whether sampling frequency comes into picture?

Comment: To know the sampling frequency in units of samples/second, you would need to know the  frequency of your sine wave in Hz.  I assume i is your counting index? Write out the formula for a sine wave and consider how you set the frequency of the sine wave with that and this should all be clearer to you.

Comment: I want to generate a sine signal with 1KHz frequency.

Comment: Ok. What sampling rate do you want to use? And are you familiar with Nyquist's Theorem? If not this should help you: https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Multimedia/node149.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to I come to know sampling frequency?

That is part of initializing your DAC. You need to read the documentation and look at the setup code for your DAC and DMA (if applicable)

> Whether sampling frequency comes into picture?

Everything in Digital Signal Processing is relative to the sample rate. A  sine wave is generated as

$$x[n] = sin(2\pi \frac{f_0}{f_s} \cdot n)$$

where $f_0$ is the frequency of your sine wave and $f_s$ your sample rate.

Comment: Thanks Hilmer. If DAC has resolution 12 and reference voltage is 3.3 for 1K signal frequency and 10K sampling frequency ,what would be the peak to peak voltage of sine ? Vref comes into picture? Or I only get "A" (amplitude of sine =1V)?

Comment: I recommend reading the data sheet of the DAC